# JAX-WS service implementation class name customization not working

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm using Maven to generate the implementation code for a web service. Originally, this code was generated from a WSDL and schema using something else (probably a wizard in Eclipse). The service implementation class name that `jaxws-maven-plugin` generates is `MyService_MyServieSOAPImpl`. When this was originally generated, the implementation class was named `MyService_SOAPImplementation`. I'm guessing that the wizard that Eclipse uses allows the user to choose the name of the implementation class. I tried using the `sei` element, but it does not work. Here's a snippet of the `wsimport` plugin in my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <id>generateMyServiceFromWSDL</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <genJWS>true</genJWS>
                    <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>otherSchema.episode</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>MyService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlLocation>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/MyService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    <sei>com.myCompany.MyService_SOAPImplementation</sei>
                    <xdonotoverwrite>true</xdonotoverwrite>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <xdebug>true</xdebug>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <target>2.0</target>
                </configuration
            </execution>
            ...
```

From some of the documents I've read, it looks like `sei` is only applicable for `wsgen`, not `wsimport`. If that is so, is there any way to force a name for the implementation class  name?

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, so from my reading, it should be possible to do this with a JAX-WS binding file, not directly in the POM file.

I've created my binding file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxws:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                            xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
                            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                            jaxws:wsdlLocation="src/main/webapp/wsdl/MyService.wsdl">
        <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='MyService']">
            <!-- change the generated SEI class -->
            <jxb:class name="MyServiceSOAPImpl"></jxb:class>
        </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

But this still doesn't seem to have any effect - wsimport is still producing the implementation as `MyService_MyServiceSOAPImpl`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your

```
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='MyService']">
```

to

```
<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:service[@name='MyServiceService']">
```

Note that the second part of the node path is `service` and not `portType`. You would use `portType` to customize the service *interface*, not the *implementation*.

As an aside it's important to note that JAX-WS bindings (seemingly) need to be in their own XML file (per WSDL) and not included with JAXB bindings.

Someone may find the list of JAX-WS bindings here to be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp227312

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps someone, two changes are required in OPs bindings.xml file to get it to work:

1. The first change was already suggested by MGE - changing the wsdl:portType in the Xpath to wsdl:service
2. The namespace for class name has to be 'jaxws', so

change to this:

```
<jaxws:class name="MyServiceSOAPImpl"/>
```

from

```
<jxb:class name="MyServiceSOAPImpl"></jxb:class>
```